# iPhone dev - number of TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to create a Tabbar that the number of tab bar items is defined by the user (let say it stores in a variable NumberOfTabBarItem). Is there a way to put tab bar items into some sort of array and display?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the UITabBar class reference, there's a property...

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *items
```

that can be accessed with...

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So you can programmatically load up an NSArray with TabBar items and use that method to display it.

Comment: How many tabbar items have you really added? Because after 16 I cannot scroll them.